# Read the json object returned by jsonp api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jsonp

This is the api I am calling: 
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars
which return top starred python projects and displays when triggered via browser.
But when I try to access the json keys from the code it says undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars&callback=?", function(result){

  alert(typeof(result));
  alert(result.total_count);
  alert(result.incomplete_results);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the callback from url:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars", function(result){

  alert(typeof(result));
  alert(result.total_count);
  alert(result.incomplete_results);

});
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a9npgduz/

Comment: I wanted to know the jsonp implementation... The solution turned out to be result.data.key_name

Comment: The api documentantion has an example that can resolve your issue: https://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks